# Assembly code elements of array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

I want to write an assembly code, for the following commands:array of 4 elements, read the elements from the user and store them, display the array with a proper message and multiply each element by 2 and I have some problems, first of all: 
I wrote this code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
ARR DB  1,2,3,4,4,4,3,1,2
MSG1    DB  'The elements of an array : $'
MSG2    DB 0DH, 0AH,'The value after multiply by 2: 

$'
.CODE
MAIN PROC

    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV CX, 9
    MOV BX, 0

    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX, MSG1
    INT 21H

DISPLAY1:
    MOV AL, ARR[BX]
    MOV AH, 2
    ADD AL, 30H
    MOV DL, AL
    INT 21H
    INC BX
LOOP DISPLAY1

    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX, MSG2
    INT 21H

    XOR CX, CX
    XOR BX, BX
    MOV CX, 9
    MOV BX, 0
MULTIPLAY:
MOV AL, 2
MUL ARR[BX]
MOV AH, 2
ADD AL, 30H
MOV DL, AL
INT 21H
INC BX
LOOP MULTIPLAY

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

**Output:**

```
The elements of an array : 123444312
The value after multiply by 2:246888624
```

It running well, but when I'm trying to ask the user to enter the number the result isn't given number in decimal digit (that gives form ascii code!)

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
ARR DB      4 DUP (?)
MSG1    DB 0DH, 0AH,    'The elements of an array : $'
MSG2    DB 0DH, 0AH,    'The value after multiply by 2: $'
MSG3    DB 0DH, 0AH,    'Enter 4 elements (numbers) : $'
.CODE
MAIN PROC

    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV CX, 4
    MOV BX, 0

    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX, MSG3
    INT 21H
INPUT:          ;This for the input elements of an array
    MOV AL, ARR[BX]
    MOV AH, 1
    SUB AL, 30H     ; I do this to convert from ASCII
    MOV DL, AL
    INT 21H
    INC BX
LOOP INPUT

    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX, MSG1
    INT 21H

    XOR CX, CX
    XOR BX, BX
    MOV CX, 4
    MOV BX, 0

DISPLAY1:       ;Output elements of an array
    MOV AL, ARR[BX]
    MOV AH, 2   
    ADD AL, 30H ; I do this to convert from ASCII
    MOV DL, AL
    INT 21H
    INC BX
LOOP DISPLAY1

    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX, MSG2
    INT 21H

    XOR CX, CX
    XOR BX, BX
    MOV CX, 4
    MOV BX, 0
MULTIPLAY:

    MOV AL, 2
    MUL ARR[BX]
    MOV AH, 2
    ADD AL, 30H  ; I do this to convert from ASCII
    MOV DL, AL
    INT 21H
    INC BX
LOOP MULTIPLAY

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

The problem in : output, display1 and multiplay functions.
**Output:**

```
Enter 4 elements (numbers) : 1234
The elements of an array : 0000
The value after multiplay by 2: 0000
```

How can I correct them?

Answer (score 2):

You have the `input` block messed up, you use the character before you even read it, and also you read from the array instead of writing. Something like this should work better:

```
INPUT:              ;This for the input elements of an array
    MOV AH, 1       ; read char with echo function
    INT 21H         ; character returned in AL
    SUB AL, 30H     ; convert from ASCII
    MOV ARR[BX], AL ; store into array
    INC BX
    LOOP INPUT
```

PS: learn to use a debugger so you can find your own mistakes.

Comment: I know if use the comment for all instruction will be easy to read more effectively, but It seems I can't get enough good documentation on assembly, at least none that's intelligible...Thank you!